# How to associate the database record with the object

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I follow the docs from here http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html
and I have a issue.

I created a relation between the category and the product model. The database has been updated correctly, model classes have right getters and setters, but if I try to run following code:

```
$product = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeStoreBundle:Product')
            ->findById(1);

$categoryName = $product->getCategory()->getName();
```

I gets an error:

> FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function getName() on a
>   non-object in
>   D:\www\Symfony\src\Acme\StoreBundle\Controller\DefaultController.php
>   line 28

I checked it out and the category model class has getName() method and it is a public method.

My **Product.orm.yml** looks like

```
Acme\StoreBundle\Entity\Product:
    type: entity
    manyToOne:
        category:
            targetEntity: Category
            inversedBy: products
            joinColumn:
                name: category_id
                referencedColumnName: id
    table: null
    fields:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
        name:
            type: string
            length: 255
        price:
            type: decimal
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

**Category.orm.yml**

```
Acme\StoreBundle\Entity\Category:
    type: entity
    oneToMany:
        products:
            targetEntity: Product
            mappedBy: category
    table: null
    fields:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
        name:
            type: string
            length: '255'
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

**Product.php**

```
...
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="products")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $category;
...
```

**Category.php**

```
...
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="category")
     */
    protected $products;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->products = new ArrayCollection();
    }
...
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are retrieving a `$category` instead of a `$product` in your sample code.

```
$product = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('AcmeStoreBundle:Product')->findOneById(1);

$categoryName = $product->getCategory()->getName();
```

note that you forgot the `getManager()`

Edit : You need to use `findOneById()` instead of `findById`. The first method will return only one single result (your object), the `findBy*` will return you an array of results on which you can't call `getCategory()` without traversing it inside a loop.

Comment: I tried different options, but it doesn't work as well. `FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function getCategory()`

Comment: Why do you have those `*.orm.yml` files ? And are you sure the product 1 has a category ?

Comment: I used console commands and it has been generated then. BTW docs say nothing about `getManager()` (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html)

Comment: Open your eyes, `CTRL+F` and type `getManager` you'll see at least 5 results including a note for "how to query database objects" :)

Comment: Big question : Do you have data (products, categories, products which have a category)  in your database ?

Comment: Yes. I have records with ID = 1.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35918/discussion-between-tristan-and-daropl)